# ¿Cómo puedo ordernar un TreeMap que tiene un Objeto como value tomando uno de los atributos del objeto como criterio?

Tags: java, poo, map, collection, orderby

Estoy implementando una clase Producto que tiene como atributos name (*String*), price(*Double*) y stock(*boolean*). En otra clase, estoy utilizando un TreeMap con un ID(int) como *key* y un Producto como *value* para guardar diferentes Productos. Al usar el *TreeMap* entiendo que por defecto se está guardando por el orden de los enteros que son la key de cada entrada.

Quisiera que, conservando el ID como *key* y el Product como *value*, lograr mostrar mi mapa también según el orden alfabético del nombre de cada Producto, en otra instancia de menor precio a mayor precio y por último si está en stock o no.

Intenté poniendo el Producto como Key e implementando Comparable a mi clase Producto y lograba ordenarlo alfabéticamente pero se me hacia lio para modificar productos en mi map después y me pareció mejor conservar el ID como key.

Intenté luego, para conservar el ID como *key*, aplicar la clase *Comparator* para asignar a mi *TreeMap*:

```
public static Comparator<Product> ordenarPorNombre = new Comparator<Product>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(Product a, Product b) {
        return a.getName().compareTo(b.getName());
    }
};
```

Luego, en el constructor de mi *TreeMap* colocaba este comparador como criterio de orden.

```
TreeMap <Integer, Product> myStore = new TreeMap(Comparadores.ordenarPorNombre);
```

En este último caso, me da el siguiente error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class com.mycompany.colecciones.ej06.Product (java.lang.Integer is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.mycompany.colecciones.ej06.Product is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

**//UPDATE//**
Siguiendo una propuesta de abordaje propuesta por ICIM en comentarios, cree el siguiente código para mostrar mi tienda de manera alfabética, utilizando un TreeSet.

```
public void showABCStore(TreeMap<Integer, Product> myStore) {
    
    TreeSet<Product> abcStore = new TreeSet(myStore.values());

    System.out.println("ABC STORE");
    for (Product product : abcStore) {
        System.out.println(product);
    }
}
```

De esta manera logro mostrar mi tienda en orden alfabético, la duda que me queda ahora es si es eficiente hacerlo de esta manera.

Este es mi main:

```java
public class MainProduct {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        TreeMap <Integer, Product> myStore = new TreeMap(Comparadores.ordenarPorNombre);
        ServiceProduct sv = new ServiceProduct();
        
        
        inicio:
        do {
            System.out.println(" *** MENU ***");
            System.out.println("1. Add products");
            System.out.println("2. Show Store ");
            System.out.println("3. Remove product");
            System.out.println("4. Modify Product");
            System.out.println("5. EXIT");
            switch (input.nextInt()) {
                case 1:
                    myStore = sv.addProduct(myStore);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    sv.showStore(myStore);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    sv.removeProduct(myStore);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    sv.modifyProduct(myStore);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("See you soon!");
                    break inicio;
                default:
                    throw new AssertionError();
            }
        } while (true);
     
    }

}
```

Esta es mi clase servicio:

```java
public class ServiceProduct {

    static int index;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public TreeMap<Integer, Product> addProduct(TreeMap<Integer, Product> myStore) {
        String end;
        boolean a = false;

        do {
            index++;
            System.out.println("Insert Product Name");
            String productName = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Is this Product in Stock? Y/N");
            String stock = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Insert Product Price");
            double price = input.nextDouble();

            if (stock.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                a = true;
            }

            myStore.put(index, new Product(productName, price, a));
            System.out.println("Would you like to add a new product? Y/N ");
            end = input.next();
            input.nextLine();

        } while (end.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

        return myStore;
    }

    public void showStore(TreeMap<Integer, Product> myStore) {
        
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Product> entry : myStore.entrySet()) {
            Object key = entry.getKey();
            Object value = entry.getValue();
            System.out.println("Product ID:" + key);
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
```

Esta es mi clase entidad:

```java
public class Product implements Comparable<Product> {

    private String name;
    private Double price;
    private boolean stock;

    public Product() {
    }

    public Product(String name, Double price, boolean stock) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public boolean isStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public void setStock(boolean stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String a = "NO";
        if (stock) {
            a = "YES";
        }
        return name + "\nPrice: " + price + "\nStock: " + a + "\n";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.name);
        hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.price);
        hash = 67 * hash + (this.stock ? 1 : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Product other = (Product) obj;
        if (this.stock != other.stock) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.name, other.name)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.price, other.price)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    //Con el implements Comparable establezco el orden natural de ordenamiento para el objeto Producto,
    //en este caso es por orden alfabético.
    public int compareTo(Product o) {
        return this.name.compareTo(o.getName());
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Haciendo una lectura a tu texto y a tu código me surge una duda ¿Has planteado tener multiples listas? Entiendo lo que pides, pero estarás haciendo un consumo muy elevado en el procesamiento de ordenación por solucitud

Comment: Realmente el tema del consumo me interesa pero aún estoy aprendiendo a como utilizar cada herramienta que hay en el framework Collections. No sabría como encararlo con múltiples listas, si se me ocurrió en un momento pasar el TreeMap a una lista y ahi pasarle el comparador por constructor pero entiendo que no es posible. ¿Es eso a lo que referís?
Gracias por tu comentario!

Comment: Me refiero a tener un treemap y una colección ordenada (TreeSet por ejemplo) trabajando en paralelo donde tengas en uno un orden por ID y en el otro un orden alfabético. Si no quieres tener la colección permanentemente puedes crearla al momento de mostrar y hacerlo in-situ. Todo depende de cómo lo quieras aprender, si bien de primeras o mal usado pero entendiendo que hace

Comment: También depende de si usas java 8 o no

Comment: Estoy usando java 8 sisi...
Bien de primeras es siempre la mejor opción.
Lo que tendría que hacer entonces es crear un TreeSet con los datos de mi TreeMap, a eso refieres? Eso lo deberia hacer a medida que voy cargando los datos en mi TreeMap hacerlo en paralelo con el TreeSet o hay alguna manera de por constructor pasar esos datos?

Comment: No sé si es lo que me estabas recomendando, pero tus comentarios me llevaron a probar esto y logré mostrar myStore alfabéticamente.

    public void showStore(TreeMap<Integer, Product> myStore) {
        TreeSet<Product> abcStore = new TreeSet(myStore.values());

Entiendo que estoy construyendo un TreeSet a partir de los valores de mi TreeMap, y como en mi entidad Product tengo el comparable de manera tal q determina el orden alfabetico como natural de ese objeto, el treeSet se ordena de esa manera...
Sería correcto?

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y añade el código allí indicando que es un `update` así podré leerlo. Pero creo que vas por el buen camino

Comment: Ahi lo actualicé! :)

Comment: Un print en toda regla (esté es el formato que consume más recursos por petición).  Si quieres usar el formato que consume menos recursos tienes que crear en TreeSet y el TreeMap a la misma altura e ir añadiendo y eliminando a la vez de los 2.

Comment: Otra cosa que no acabo de ver es el motivo de tener una clase servicio cuando todos los productos están en la lista. Entonces surge mi duda de ¿creas el Treemap en una clase diferente a la de productos, por?

Answer (score 1):

Voy por partes:

Un `Map` **no está diseñado para ser ordenado por valor**. La finalidad de un `Map` es poder acceder rápidamente a un valor, teniendo una clave. Si cambiaras el orden del map basándote en el valor en vez de en la clave, ¿Para qué tener la clave fuera en primer lugar? ¿No te da la sensación de que el ID está fuera de lugar?

Esto me lleva a una disyuntiva. O bien el ID está como tiene que estar, como un valor *aparte* de tu Producto y entonces la carga de ordenación recae sobre el ID, o bien el ID no debería estar aparte del Producto, sino formar parte de él.

En el primer caso, la ordenación por valor se te va a volver muy farragosa (como ya has visto)

En el segundo caso, lo que se me ocurre es que metas el ID dentro del Producto:

```
public class Product implements Comparable<Product> {
    private int ID;
    // otras propiedades, getters, setters, constructor y lógica varia...
}
```

Y que en vez de un TreeMap uses un TreeSet (que, incidentalmente, utiliza un TreeMap por debajo para ordenar):

```
Set<Product> set = new TreeSet<>();

// Creas el producto normalmente, y a la hora de añadir el ID se lo añades al Producto
Product product = new Product();
product.setID(10);

// añades el producto a tu Set, que se ordena automáticamente
set.add(product)

// y un ejemplo de cómo mostrar tu tienda desde éste planteamiento:
public void showStore(TreeSet<Product> myStore) {
    
    for (Product product: myStore) {
        System.out.println("Product ID:" + product.getID());
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}

// o también puedes añadir el ID al toString() para reducirlo todavía más
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.ID + "" // y lo que sea que quieras ponerle
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Esto no es una respuesta

Es un comentario, pero no me cabe (por tamaño), ni estaría formateado

```
public class Product implements Comparable<Product> {
public static TreeSet<Product> abcStore = new TreeSet();
public static TreeMap <Integer, Product> myStore = new TreeMap(Comparadores.ordenarPorNombre);

//método público y static para eliminar de TreeMap y de TreeSet

    private String name;
    private Double price;
    private boolean stock;

    public Product() {
    }

    public Product(String name, Double price, boolean stock) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.stock = stock;
//add to TreeMap
//add to TreeSet
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public boolean isStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public void setStock(boolean stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String a = "NO";
        if (stock) {
            a = "YES";
        }
        return name + "\nPrice: " + price + "\nStock: " + a + "\n";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.name);
        hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.price);
        hash = 67 * hash + (this.stock ? 1 : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Product other = (Product) obj;
        if (this.stock != other.stock) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.name, other.name)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.price, other.price)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    //Con el implements Comparable establezco el orden natural de ordenamiento para el objeto Producto,
    //en este caso es por orden alfabético.
    public int compareTo(Product o) {
        return this.name.compareTo(o.getName());
    }
}
```

Te dejé en comentarios (//) lo que faltaría. Esto es lo que quise decir en los comentarios (chat de SO) como una forma de bajo consumo por petición